# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark

This is my first Spark Stream application. The setup is as following

3 nodes running a spark cluster. One master node and two slaves.

The application is a simple java application streaming from twitter and dependencies managed by maven.

Here is the code of the application

```
public class SimpleApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("spark://rethink-node01:7077");

        JavaStreamingContext sc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(1000));

        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey("ConsumerKey")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("ConsumerSecret")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("AccessToken")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("TokenSecret");

        OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization(cb.build());

        JavaDStream<Status> tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(sc, auth);

         JavaDStream<String> statuses = tweets.map(new Function<Status, String>() {
             public String call(Status status) throws Exception {
                return status.getText();
            }
        });

         statuses.print();;

         sc.start();

         sc.awaitTermination();

    }

}
```

here is the pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SparkFirstTry</groupId>
    <artifactId>SparkFirstTry</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.test.sparkTest.SimpleApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The application starts successfully but no tweets comes and this exception is thrown

```
15/11/08 15:55:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 78, 192.168.122.39): java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1163)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.readObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1707)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1160)
    ... 20 more
```

I run the application locally from Eclipse. It is clear the problem is in the dependencies but I can not figure out how to solve it.

Comment: check your dependencies contains org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter or not?

Comment: nop, it does not exist

Comment: Check which jar consists org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter and add the jars as dependency in your pom.xml file.

Comment: it is already included in the pom file (spark-streaming-twitter_2.10) but when I search for org.apache.spark.streaming from the dependencies  hierarchy tab I can not find it !!!!!!

Comment: Check your repository and also right click on project and check your maven dependencies. If it is not there then error will be shown else it dependencies will be present there. And right click on the project and select maven and select update option to update.

Comment: The jar is in the repo. I opened the jar and make sure the specified class exists. I did maven update project. I also copied the jar file into the lib directory of all the spark nodes but the problem still the same

Comment: How you are executing the jar file. Because while executing the jar file all the dependecny jars should be in the classpath. ie) java -jar <jarfilename> -cp <classpath of jar files>. If it is in eclipse while executing add it to classpath

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94543/discussion-between-fanooos-and-shriram).